# Use Git's commit message cleanup mode from commit-msg hook

Tags: git, githooks

[`git help commit`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) says the following:

```
--cleanup=<mode>
   This option determines how the supplied commit message should be
   cleaned up before committing. The <mode> can be strip, whitespace,
   verbatim, or default.

   strip
       Strip leading and trailing empty lines, trailing whitespace,
       and #commentary and collapse consecutive empty lines.

   whitespace
       Same as strip except #commentary is not removed.

   verbatim
       Do not change the message at all.

   default
       Same as strip if the message is to be edited. Otherwise
       whitespace.
```

I'd like to determine which cleanup mode is going to be applied from the commit-msg [hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) (correctly using the `commit.cleanup` [config value](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) when necessary). [I run some validations on my commit messages](https://github.com/mkantor/hooks/blob/master/commit-msg) and I want to make sure I'm seeing exactly what Git is planning on using.

Alternatively, I'll accept a way to grab the commit message text post-cleanup (maybe I can trick Git into cleaning it up for me?). This would be great for my use case, since then I wouldn't have to worry about re-implementing any cleanup modes.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, in current(ish) git source, the cleanup mode is not passed through to the hook in any way.  The argument to `--cleanup` is stored only in the (`static`, local to `builtin/commit.c`) variable `cleanup_mode` and not exported (e.g., as an argument or environment variable) to the various hooks.

(It should be easy to add an environment variable containing the setting.  If you want to experiment with this yourself, see `builtin/commit.c` function `parse_and_validate_options`; put in a call to `setenv()` with appropriate arguments.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm doing in a commit-msg hook. (I need to check line length, but ignore long lines that will be stripped as comments.)

- check `git config commit.cleanup`.
- if blank or `default`, check `git var GIT_EDITOR`: if it is equal to `:`, then cleanup mode is `whitespace`, otherwise it is `strip`.
- Pray that my team continues its blissful ignorance of the `--cleanup` option of git commit.

The reason for this, per `git help hooks` (see the pre-commit entry), is that all the commit-adjacent hooks receive `GIT_EDITOR=:` when invoked in a context where the commit will not be edited. For merge, and for commit in the absence of `--cleanup`, this is enough to determine the cleanup mode.